# Creating Google Cloud Platform Projects without Console page.

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to create Google Cloud Platform projects without Console web page, because I think about creating multiple projects.

Since I checked the gcloud and it only supports project describe and list for now. 
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/projects/

Is there a way to create projects without Console web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of June 22 2015, there is no API to manage projects. This is simply not possible currently.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, just to bring the answer up-to-date, this can now be done with the gcloud projects command line, as described in the following documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/